# Почему не работает .css() для элемента массивоподобного объекта?

Tags: jquery

.css() не работает для определенного элемента массивоподобного объекта, в то время как конструкция .style выполняет изменения стиля как надо.
Еще .css() работает для всего массивоподобного объекта.
Почему .css() не изменяет стиль отдельного элемента?
Какой выход из ситуации, не прибегая к конструкции .style?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var row = $('.row');
    var strip = $('.strip');
  row[1].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
  strip.css({'backgroundColor' : 'yellow'});
  row[0].css({'backgroundColor' : 'yellow'});/*это не работает*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="margin-bottom:100px;">
        <tr class="row">
  <td class="cell">1-1</td>
  <td class="cell">1-2</td>
  <td class="cell">1-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="row">
  <td class="cell">2-1</td>
  <td class="cell">2-2</td>
  <td class="cell">2-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class= "row">
  <td class="cell">3-1</td>
  <td class="cell">3-2</td>
  <td class="cell">3-3</td>
 </tr>
<tr class="strip">
  <td class="cell">1-1</td>
  <td class="cell">1-2</td>
  <td class="cell">1-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="strip">
  <td class="cell">2-1</td>
  <td class="cell">2-2</td>
  <td class="cell">2-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class= "strip">
  <td class="cell">3-1</td>
  <td class="cell">3-2</td>
  <td class="cell">3-3</td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Множественный селектор в массиве держит указатели на дом элементы, но они не объекты jQuery, и соответственно не будет иметь никаких его методов. 
Вам нужно из указателя сделать объект jQuery:

```
$(row[0]).css({'backgroundColor' : 'yellow'});
```

Но правильнее так:

```
row.eq(0).css({'backgroundColor' : 'yellow'});
```

Для первого элемента есть еще вариант `row.first()...`

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = document.getElementsByClassName('.row');
```

Comment: Если использовать массив и .css() эффект будет тот же, то есть работать не будет с отдельным элементом.